# Word Tokenization When There is No Space

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am wondering for the term in Machine Learning, Deep Learning, or in Natural Language Processing that split the word in a paragraph when there is no space between them.

example:
"iwanttocook"

become:
"i want to cook"

It wouldn't be easy since you do not have the character to tokenize the word.

I appreciate any help

Comment: You need a dictionary with all known English words, and analyze the text semantically character by character until you get a "known word" of your dictionary and put it apart, then continue with remaining letters. That's how you can get this kind of output.

Comment: The problem is called word segmentation. It is more commonly applied to languages that don't delimit words.

Comment: J. Smith (i did not know how to summon someone) But if i did this in this way, it would be computationally expensive right? because you should match char by char

Comment: Dan D, thanks dan. word segmentation sounds familiar to me

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using the `polyglot` package. There is an option for morphological analysis.

This kind of analysis is based on [morfessor](https://morfessor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) models trained on most frequent words to encounter morphemes ("primitive units of syntax, the smallest individually meaningful elements in the utterances of a language").

From the [documentation](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MorphologicalAnalysis.html):

```
from polyglot.text import Text

blob = "Wewillmeettoday."
text = Text(blob)
text.language = "en"
print(text.morphemes)
```

The output would be:

```
WordList([u'We', u'will', u'meet', u'to', u'day', u'.'])
```

Note that if you want to start working with polyglot, you should first read the documentation carefully, as there are a few things to consider, for example the [downloading](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Download.html) of language specific models.

Comment: Maybe you could also briefly explain how it's done, because I think the author also wanted to know how these libraries manage to make it possible.

Comment: thanks trotta. but I wonder if the lib can do sematically. example "islandmadebysomemagic" whether should be "is land made by some magic" or "island made by some magic". thanks anyway

Comment: I don't know how the package handles specific requests, but you should give it a try. I'm working with this kind of NLP myself and for now it's the best tool for such analyses I came across.

Answer (score 0):

I created an simple application using Scala to do this.

https://github.com/shredder47/Nonspaced-Sentence-Tokenizer